# How to separate web client project and web API project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I am developing a SPA application on ASP.NET 5 and I wanted to go one step further and separate the client (js, html, etc.) and the web api projects so that there is clear distinction between client and the server. Apparently there are number of technical issues that complicate things:

- How can I include the js/html/etc. files in the resulting published project? (Ideally I want to be able to edit js/html and see the result in the browser on the fly). There is on way that I found to have a linked folder.
- I want to share some of the javascript files even further e.g. angular services in Cordova js projects
- There is very nice feature in mvc6 with environments that is not easily done in js project and I would have to still use some Index.cshtml to use it, but this is not critical though since I can use gulp to do similar stuff
- How will the js know the URL of the api (this can probably be just done using gulp as well in some script with configuration)

I am not 100% sure this is a good idea at all, but maybe someone has tried it and can share experience and pros/cons of this approach. For now the most important problem seem to be of including the client project into the service project somehow so that they are joined into one web application that I can deploy in a way that does not make development harder.

Comment: since more than 5 years from this one was asked, can you answer yourself now? :)